# How would I use the GET request here?

Tags: c#, node.js, express, windows-forms-designer

So I have a C# App and a express server, the express server has a JSON file in it with a certain file name, how do I make a **Get request** to the server from the C# app that find that certain file and send it back to the C# app.

The app talks to the server, so far it sends a JSON which the server then saves as a .json file with the req body. Now I need it to talk to the server and get that file content.

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var url = "http://localhost:3000/user";
    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

```
This is the post req to the server at the moment and it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this straight, the Express server is in your control? What does the response of the POST contain?

We cannot help you if we don't know the specifics of the server.

It's common for requests like these to return an identifier as a result of success for a POST request. So, you request to create a resource in the server, the server creates it, maybe saves it in a storage, and returns an identifier to that resource.

What you will need to do is grab that identifier and use it later in a GET request. For example, a GET request to http://localhost:3000/user/123.